# Integer promotion (MISRA C:2012 Rule 7.2)

Tags: c, integer, misra, integer-promotion

MISRA enforces the use of the `U` suffix for unsigned integer constants

```
uint32_t the_answer = 0x42U;
```

I feel the `U` is a bit boilerplate because the line is very understandable without it.

So I am wondering how much this rule is important and if `unsigned int x = 1` is truely a bad example of implicit integer promotion.

Comment: @user3386109, not really. You can follow MISRA and create deviations. So I can disable from this rule if I find a rationale.

Comment: Overall this rule is quite rigid. There's a whole lot of cases where the implicit signed type of the literal clearly doesn't matter. Rather than making a very intricate rule only covering the dangerous cases, they just enforce U all over the place.

Comment: "MISRA enforces the use of the U suffix for unsigned integer constants" --> Not quite correct.  Without the `U`, `0x42` is not an _unsigned integer constant_.  It is a _hexadecimal constant_ of type `int`.  The `U` makes it of type `unsigned` and it is still a _hexadecimal constant_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, the U in this specific example is superfluous as per an exception to Rule 10.3:

"A non-negative integer constant expression of essentially signed type may be assigned to an object of essentially unsigned type if its value can be represented in that type."

Therefore, you are fine to assign a signed integer less than 7FFF FFFF to this unsigned 32-bit object.

Comment: Note that this does not even require a deviation; you are not attempting to justify the use of an unsigned constant without declaring it unsigned, you are using a signed constant under an exception to 10.3