# Canonical unsigned litteral suffix when used as array indices

Tags: c, indexing, types, c99

I read the advice for [using `size_t` for array indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174850/what-is-the-correct-type-for-array-indexes-in-c).

What would be the standard and portable way to write `unsigned` litterals?

Why isn't the canonical way:

```
size_t i;
unsigned char uchar[10U];

uchar[0U]=10U;

for(i=2U;i<uchar[0U];i++) {
    uchar[i]=i;
    printf("%u\n",uchar[i]);
}
```

Comment: The normal, standard way to write the literal indexes and sizes as integers is as a plain decimal (usually) integer — `unsigned char uchar[10]; uchar[9] = '\0';` etc.  Anything else is unusual — there has to be a good reason to do it (and there is seldom a good reason, so it is seldom done).  With variables — using `size_t` is reasonable, but using plain `int` is also usually OK.  You can run into problems with plain `int` before you run into problems with `size_t`, but you're dealing with extremes.

Answer (score 4):

The `U` there in `0U` is just noise - because it is a simple constant its type does not really matter. What is worse there is no suffix for `size_t` specifically.

You actually need the suffixes very seldom - and even then, more often than not, to silence a nagging compiler.

The `size_t` advice applies to *objects* that are meant to store array indices and *index calculations* with unknowns, or things like `1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 10` for the array dimension calculation  - these should happen in `size_t` where there is a danger of integer overflow or wraparound.

Comment: Is writing uchar[1U] recommended?

Comment: @OneArb No. The `U` is not needed, so it's just fluff that makes your code harder to understand.

Comment: @JL2210 Thanks. I got the idea from: Constants of unsigned type should have a "U" https://rules.sonarsource.com/c/RSPEC-854

Comment: but indices used in brackets need not be unsigned or non-negative. `a[-1]` is perfectly fine provided that `a` currently points to 2..nth element in an array.

Comment: @OneArb That page is wrong, then. Implicit conversion rules already cover this.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The question is meant for those who wish to follow the size_t advice as per the link in the question first line.

Comment: @JL2210 Ok https://rules.sonarsource.com/ is making a code analyzer and apply the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703624/integer-promotion-misra-c2012-rule-7-2

Comment: @OneArb but you need to understand *what* the question there asks and what the answers are for.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks I just found it.

Answer (score 1):

The standard and portable way to write unsigned literals is by writing `<number>U`.

However, this isn't recommended on array indices, for various reasons:

1. Most of the constant array indices that you'll be using are below `INT_MAX` and `UINT_MAX`.
   If you are using constant array indices these big, you should really consider rethinking your approach.
2. These just make your code larger (if only by a few bytes) and harder to understand.